# HTML 5 Print API

Tags: html, printing

Is there going to be an HTML5 Standard print api?

Besides using @media queries, it would be nice to control the page printing page by page.  So for instance if printing 100 page document you are not loading 100 full images into browser memory.  Or is there a good strategy for this kind of workflow that people have tried.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the most control and consistent results from browser-to-browser, I've used wkhtmltopdf and/or princexml to render PDF on the server, and then either download the PDF or email it directly to the printer. That gives you control over the exact output. A 300-page PDF might be a few megabytes in size, which is not prohibitive to download.

If you want to render in the browser, you can still do that with print-specific CSS, that should give you control over page breaks, visual design, etc. However, not every browser supports everything you'd want for print (hyphenation, for example), and you don't necessarily get consistent results.

Do you have a specific need to limit browser memory usage?